# Spring security authenticate against local linux account

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I would like to use the existing user accounts on my redhat server for users to login with.
The redhat server uses active directory to authenticate with, but I cannot get access to authenticate with AD directly.

My web app will be using spring security.

Is it possible to use the redhat server's user accounts to authenticate against with spring security?
(note: su does not support passwords given on the command line with my server ("-S")).

Comment: Answered myself in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778188/spring-security-jaas-authentication-authorization-issue/24632489

Answer (score 1):

I was digging around but could not find a sample code, but you could use PAM.

I found this project in GitHub https://github.com/kohsuke/libpam4j, which is a Java implementation of PAM (I don't know if it is active or if it will provide what you need).

Also, if sudo doesn't support passwords, you could try with `expect`

```
spawn "/bin/su" "bob"
expect "Password:"
send "userspassword\r"
expect "^\\$"
send "ls"
expect -re "^\\$"
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: I dont have expect either :(

Comment: Did you try the GitHub project?

Comment: I'll give it a go once I get our admin to set it up with PAM

Comment: Works with a whole bunch of configuration and custom code. Wishing spring came with this set up out of the box.